# Closing a pipe does not send EOF to other end

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I would like to run an external command from a C program. Let's say, as minimal working example, that I want to run the 'cat' command. I use use fork() and execl() to spawn the new process, and I communicate with it via pipes.

Now that's where my problem is. In a terminal I would tell 'cat' that I am done with my input by pressing CTRL-D. Here I am trying to do so by closing the file descriptor -- see the line with close(outpipefd[1]) in the code below -- but this does not seem to work. My code stalls as 'cat' is waiting for more input.

My code is as follows... What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid=0;
    int inpipefd[2];
    int outpipefd[2];

    /*
        We create the pipes for communicating with the child process
    */

    pipe(inpipefd);
    pipe(outpipefd);

    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        /*
            Child
        */

        dup2(outpipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(inpipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(inpipefd[1],STDERR_FILENO);

        /*
            We spawn the process
        */

        execl("/bin/cat","cat",(char *)(NULL));

        /*
            Nothing below this line should be executed by child process.
            If so, it means that the execl function wasn't successfull, so lets exit!
        */

        exit(1);
    }

    /*
        Parent.
        Close unused pipe ends.
    */
    
    close(outpipefd[0]);
    close(inpipefd[1]);

    /*
        Now we can write to outpipefd[1] and read from inpipefd[0]
    */

    char *greeting="Hello world!\n";
    write(outpipefd[1],greeting,strlen(greeting));

    /*
        Here I believe that closing the pipe should be equivalent to
        pressing CTRL-D in a terminal, therefore terminating the cat command...
        This is unfortunately not the case!
    */

    close(outpipefd[1]);

    while(1)
    {
        char buf[256];

        for(int c=0;c<256;c++)
            buf[c]=0;
        
        if(read(inpipefd[0], buf, 256)<=0)
            break;

        printf("OUTPUT: %s\n", buf);
    }

    /*
        Send SIGKILL signal to the child process
    */

    int status;

    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close _both_ of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child still has both ends of both pipes opened, because you never closed any of your FDs in it. Until every FD referring to the write end of a pipe is closed, it won't return EOF.

Comment: As a hint to OP, the child can close both ends of each pipe after the respective `dup2` calls.

Comment: Many thanks Joseph and Ian, works like a charm! I will accept the answer as soon as it is possible (in 3 minutes!).

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I can't find it on man pages for both pipe and close

Answer (score 2):

You have also to close the unused pipe ends in the child, or there will be still things open that block the other end.  close what you don't use in parent **and child**, and you will get the EOFs.